# Set the largest element in each row to be one and others zero

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB like

```
t2 =

    0.4366    0.4298    0.5907
    0.9401    0.5358    0.6136
    0.2305    0.5212    0.9759
    0.9545    0.5572    0.9042
```

I want to get the largest element on each row and set them to be one, the rest to be zero. So

```
t2 = 

      0    0    1
      1    0    0
      0    0    1
      1    0    0
```

How can I do that with the fewest commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner in Matlab:

```
t2 = [0.4366 0.4298 0.5907;
      0.9401 0.5358 0.6136;
      0.2305 0.5212 0.9759;
      0.9545 0.5572 0.9042];
t2 = double(bsxfun(@eq, t2, max(t2, [], 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate example, not as elegant... but still nice and understandable. And gets the job done.

```
for i = 1:length(t2(:,1))
    t2(i,:)=t2(i,:)==max(t2(i,:));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward with `sparse` and the second output argument to `max`:

```
[~,icol] = max(M,[],2);
B = full(sparse(1:size(M,1),icol,1,size(M,1),size(M,2)))
```

Or with `spconvert` instead of `sparse`:

```
B = full(spconvert([(1:size(M,1))',icol,ones(size(M,1),1);[size(M) 0]]))
```

Test data:

```
M = [0.4366,0.4298,0.5907;...
     0.9401,0.5358,0.6136;...
     0.2305,0.5212,0.9759;...
     0.9545,0.5572,0.9042]; % OP's t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not remembering the exact syntax for saying this in MATLAB right off hand, but here is how you can do it in Python with NumPy arrays, and the syntax will more or less be exactly the same in MATLAB. You won't use the `None` trick I've used to expand the array dimensions, though.

(Note: I used my own random set of data, not yours)

```
In [311]: t2/t2.max(axis=1)[:,None]
Out[311]:
array([[ 0.96452099,  0.19900529,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.36581245,  0.91631999],
       [ 0.62747397,  0.96969966,  1.        ],
       [ 0.07238682,  0.59855665,  1.        ]])

In [312]: np.floor(t2/t2.max(axis=1)[:,None])
Out[312]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: In Matlab: `floor(t2./(max(t2,[],2)*ones(1,size(t2,2))))`